# max connection MySql reached during tests

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, phpunit, database-connection

When i launch my PHPUnit test suite i reached the max connection limit (200) for MySQL.

The hot fix was to set max_connection to 500, but i'm looking for a better solution in Zend Framework 2 context.

I tried to put some tearDown method, but no luck it seems to be useless or imcomplete solution.

This is a sample of code :

```
protected function tearDown()
{
    // i have two entitymanager
    $this->getObjectManager()->get('doctrine.connection.orm_alternate')->close();
    $this->getObjectManager()->get('doctrine.connection.orm_default')->close();
    $this->application = null;
    gc_collect_cycles();
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

I also tried to use processIsolation turn to true but some test are so long that i assumed that my console has froze or something like that....

**With doctrine2 connection, and Zend Framework, how can I prevent this "Too many connection" during PHPunit tests ?**

so far with tips of @awons i tried to modify
`$this->getObjectManager()->get('doctrine.connection.orm_alternate')->close();`

to 
`$this->getObjectManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_alternate')->close();`

I checked if teardown was called, yes.

Something i don't understand is : on each test, a new instance of my connections are created, why this is not the same instance ? (like singleton or Registry) ?
But this instance is never closed even it's not used after the test passed.

I misse something but don't know what.

Comment: Sorry but the question is?

Comment: which version of php do you use?

Comment: Php : 5.4.19, with Doctrine 2, Zend Framework 2.3.3 And PHPunit 4.1

Comment: In a previous project, i have the same problem(500 max_connection needed) with php 5.3. When we switch to php 5.5 no problem at all, so if you can try to run your test on a more recent version of php you can aspect better result. So is not your code! Is only php.... :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you tell me why php 5.5 is better for this ? i can't find in changelog an update wich explain this. A link maybe ?

Comment: sorry, i don't know why....

Comment: I installed php 5.5, same problem, any new ideas ?

Comment: Did you try to close the manager itself: `$this->getObjectManager()->close()`?

Comment: in fact, and it's not clear, my method getObjectManager return a Zend\ServiceManager instance, and in my code ->get('doctrine.connection.orm_alternate') is my ObjectManager with Method close, so yes my code is pretty much you asked me to tried :)

Comment: What does this say: `get_class($this->getObjectManager()->get('doctrine.connection.orm_default'))`?

Comment: Doctrine\DBAL\Connection

Comment: Are you able to get doctrine object? Something like `$this->getObjectManager()->get('doctrine')`?

Comment: hum, no unable to create an instance for doctrine, maybe the alias is not correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78328/discussion-between-awons-and-hooli).

Comment: Do you setup your connection/application in your tests bootstrap or in the tests or setUp() method itself? Try to create your connection prior test execution itself. then your connection should be reused.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved a similar problem before doing it this way:

```
protected static $my_db_for_testing

public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    //create your DB connection once, here.
    $self::$my_db_for_testing = new DbConnectionWhatever()
}

protected function setUp()
{
    $this->my_obj_to_test = new MyObject();
    $this->my_obj_to_test->setDb($this->my_db_for_testing);
}



public function testOne()
{
    //normal test here
}

public static function tearDownAfterClass()
{
    //close the DB connection here
}
```

}

Comment: Fatal error : Using $this when not in object context for both beforeClass and EndClass solving this involve too much coding for modifying my unit test architecture. No time available on this for now

Comment: any reason why this is needed/works? I still run into max connections errors even tho each connection is opened, used and then closed with setup()/teardown() before the next unit test runs.

Answer (score 3):

We always configure with settings like:

set-variable = max_connections=1500

set-variable = max_user_connections=300

Where there are < 10 users that will connect to the server. This leaves connections open for super users. We typically have 2-3 application users for our mysql servers. So, with 3, only 900 connections could be used up by our users. You can additionally restrict per user connections if you want to tweak it even further.

Comment: Like a i said, i tried this hot fix setting max_connections to 1500, but my project grows up and it's not solving the problem. Next year i will have this settings set to 10 000 ? No.

Answer (score 3):

Do your tests need to be run against MySql?

With Doctrine, you can use a sqlite db for testing. Unless there is a specific need to use MySql, this is a method that can improve your testing process and isolate you from issues outside of your actual unit tests.

Additionally, you might potentially see speed gains by doing tests against an in memory DB.

Comment: My tests are functionnal too, my project needs data and sometimes in my test i need to do real SQL queries, because our database is not reliable, somes test are only for control data...

Comment: sqlite can provide data, and can be queried with SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend to read the chapter on [fixtures](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html). To avoid creating a new connection for each test, use `setUpBeforeClass()` to establish your DB connection once and reuse that connection for each of your tests.

```
<?php
  class DatabaseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
  {
     protected static $dbh;

     public static function setUpBeforeClass()
     {
       self::$dbh = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
     }

     public static function tearDownAfterClass()
     {
       self::$dbh = NULL;
     }
  }
?>
```